# How to create a constructor of an object from a extended class that contains as arguments two initial object?

Tags: java, object, extends

I m new in Java and I have a simple problem:

I have the following class Point:

```
public class Point {

    private int yAxis;
    private int xAxis;

    public Point (int x, int y)
    {
        xAxis = x;
        yAxis = y;
    }
}
```

I created a new class that extends class Point. I want my new class to take as arguments two objects Point. I wrote the following code but I receive the error "Implicit super constructor MyPoint() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor". How can I fix the problem?

Thanks in advance!

```
public class Rectangle extends Point {

    private int length1;
    private int height1;

    public Rectangle(int x, int y, int l, int h) {
        super(x, y);
        l = length1;
        h = height1;
    }

    public Rectangle(Point topLeft, Point bottonRight) {


    }
}
```

Comment: And just an FYI: it doesn't make sense to assign a field value to a constructor param value. For example, you write: `l = length1`.

Comment: Also... a more clear way of asking your question would be "How do I make a subclass that depends on its superclass?"

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned that you should not use inheritance. I fully agree. But I find Effective Java to be such a good reference on matters like this, that I think it's worthy of its own answer. Please see [Effective Java Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA81&lpg=PA81&dq=effective+java+favor+composition+over+inheritance&source=bl&ots=yYEkNlw3O0&sig=kICbHoUBPsxVL5xLzEDABDcD9SA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aL0CT9jMDcLu0gHgqsGXAg&sqi=2&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) for a more in-depth discussion.

Comment: I really recommend reading the whole book too!

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `extends Point` just because the `Rectangle` class mentions `Points`. The `extends` keyword is used to declare an *is-a* relationship. Ask youself *is a Rectangle a Point?*

If you're trying to say "This class will be *using* the Point-class" you should probably just `import` the `Point` class.

(You fix the error by removing `extends Point`.)

Comment: Could I solve the problem without removing exteds Point?

Comment: Yes (but it would be silly :)  Since a `Rectangle` then *is a* `Point` you need to provide the `Point`-constructor with arguments (`x` and `y`). You do this by adding for instance `super(0, 0)` in the top of the second `Rectangle` constructor.

Comment: @voimak: you could also invoke the super constructor with the x and y properties of the `topLeft` Point: `super(topLeft.getX(), topLeft.getY())` but this is only if you really want to be able to treat a rectangle as a point.

Comment: what about the bottomRight Point, i have to make the same super(bottomRight.getX(), bottomRight.getY())? Thanks!